# WP Post Meta Tags not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, plugins, meta-tags

I have been trying to associate CUSTOM data to each of my WP POSTS using the following piece of code :

```
if($condition === true){
   if ( ! update_post_meta ($post_id, '_someData', $someVariable) ) {
    add_post_meta($post_id, '_someData', $someVariable);
   }
}
```

However, seems like the META VALUE is RESET to default i.e. Zero OR Blank. Our WordPress website has around 40 plugins, and I think one of these WordPress plugins, is coming in my way of doing things. All of my logic works fine, on a demo WordPres website. Is there a way for me to have total control to set the META Value for a given POST ? Also, is there a way where I can be notified that the META Key is about to change and then I can decide whether OR not to change the Meta Value ?

Any pointers or reference URL's can be of great help. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call `update_post_meta` in either scenario. Calling `add_post_meta()` is not necessary and could be causing this problem.

From the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta):

The function `update_post_meta()` updates the value of an existing meta key (custom field) for the specified post.

This may be used in place of `add_post_meta()` function. The first thing this function will do is make sure that `$meta_key` already exists on `$post_id`. If it does not, `add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)` is called instead and its result is returned.